# Overriding UIButton setAttributedTitle:forState:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to override `UIButton setAttributedTitle:forState:` in order to set some default kerning everywhere the subclass is used. This code creates the correct `NSAttributedString` and works for any UIButtons I've created with Interface Builder:

```
- (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    NSMutableAttributedString* attributeText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:title] mutableCopy];
    [attributeText addAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName: @(kDefaultKerning)} range:[attributeText fullRange]];
    self.titleLabel.attributedText = attributeText;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But it doesn't work for any of the UIButton subclass that I create in code:

```
[_myButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So I tried calling super instead of `self.titleLabel.attributedText = attributeText;`:

```
[super setAttributedTitle:title forState:state];
```

Which works for the button created in code, but now it doesn't work for the Interface Builder buttons.

Since as far as I know, Interface Builder just calls setAttributedText anyway, what gives? How can I get this override to work for both code-generated buttons and Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. Of course `[super setAttributedTitle:title forState:state];` wasn't working, because I was setting it to `title` instead of `attributedText`.

Solution:

```
- (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    NSMutableAttributedString* attributeText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:title] mutableCopy];
    [attributeText addAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName: @(kDefaultKerning)} range:[attributeText fullRange]];
    [super setAttributedTitle:attributeText forState:state];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```